Can a sentence starting with "when ..... " function as an object of another sentence?
This is said by a driver who has just argued with an official who fines drivers for parking cars in no-parking areas.

The thing that probably annoyed me most was when he said I can tell you where not to park, but I can't tell you where to park.

Using a sentence starting with "when ....." as the object of another sentence seems interesting to me, because the structure seems to require an object like this: "The thing that annoyed me most was his saying ...". However, I don't know whether a sentence starting with "when" can function as an object. So, I would expect it to be:

The thing that probably annoyed me most was his saying I can tell you where not to park, but I can't tell you where to park.

Am I right in my thinking?

We often insert a "dummy it" in contexts such as "I like [it] when you do that", but I think only pedants would say when you do that can't function as an object without the dummy pronoun. It's just more or less idiomatic in various specific contexts. Hardly anyone would expect two dummy "it"s in, say, I know it when it's raining, but they might feel different about I hate when it's raining, It's just idiomacy, though - not a matter "syntactic rules".

It's better to understand the "when" phrase as an ellipsis: "What annoyed me was (the moment / the point) when he said..." Or perhaps "(his attitude / his hypocrisy) when he said..." This gets you your nominative object as well as the idiomatic phrasing.
